# Groovy catch statement weird behavior

Tags: exception, groovy

I have the following 2 groovy snippets that should do the same but they don't.

```
try {
  throw new RuntimeException()
} catch (IllegalStateException) {
  println("hello!")
}
```

The output from this `'hello!'`

```
try {
  throw new RuntimeException()
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  println("hello!")
}
```

And the output from this one is an unexpected exception:

```
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at 2.run(2.groovy:2)
```

Please note the only difference is that in one snippet there is no `e` parameter in the catch block.

I'm running the following version of groovy and JVM.

`groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.0.5 JVM: 1.6.0_37 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux`

Is this an expected behavior or is it a bug in the compiler?
Thanks

Comment: It didnt make any difference when I added the `;` terminator. Thanks!

Comment: @Unihedron `;` are optional in Groovy

Comment: The exception in the second snippet is expected. Perhaps you wanted to throw `IllegalStateException` and catch `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first case, you're introducing a *variable* called `IllegalStateException`. It's equivalent to:

```
try {
  throw new RuntimeException()
} catch (Exception IllegalStateException) {
  println("hello!")
}
```

In the second case, you're *only* catching `IllegalStateException`, which isn't the type of the exception being thrown, hence the `catch` block doesn't catch it.

It's *not* equivalent to the C# meaning, where you'd be saying that you only want to catch `IllegalStateException`, but you don't need a variable for it as you don't care about the exception object.

See the "Catch any exception" part of the [Groovy style and language feature guidelines for Java developers](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+style+and+language+feature+guidelines+for+Java+developers) documentation.

Comment: It's equivalent to the first snippet.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: Yup, had just confirmed that :)

Comment: It would be better using as `catch (IllegalStateException | Exception e)` to cover both types of exception. @MauroCiancio

Comment: @dmahapatro: Why? `IllegalStateException` *is* an `Exception`, so it already covers both...

Comment: To catch anything other than `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @dmahapatro: Okay, at this point I don't understand your comment at all. If you want to catch all exceptions, use `catch (Exception e)`. There's no need to use a more complicated form.

Comment: I should have mentioned `catch (IllegalStateException | RuntimeException e)`, if specifically those two types of exception needs handling.

Comment: @dmahapatro: No, that still doesn't make any sense, as `IllegalStateException` is also a `RuntimeException`. I don't know about Groovy, but in Java that gives a compile-time error: "Alternatives in a multi-catch statement cannot be related by subclassing"

Comment: Got me here. This is going no where. That will be irrelevant I agree.

Comment: @dmahapatro: That sounds like a design mistake in Groovy then, IMO :(

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you are not catching the exception thrown; so that behavior is expected. In the first case, 'Exception' is the variable assigned to the exception thrown. Print that out and you'll see it's "java.lang.RuntimeException".